# WINE - Cannot install adobe flash player (file not found)

Tags: wine, flash, playonlinux, adobe

I have a problem installing Adobe Flash Player in Playonlinux or Wine standalone. I have read all related threads and have a basic understanding of how Wine works.
I have downloaded the setup file (Adobe Flash Player 26), when I run it the install progress bar goes to 100% but then I get "File not found" in PLayonlinux and the specific error when i run it from the terminal using Wine is :

```
fixme:atl:AtlAxWinInit version 0300 semi-stub
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Macromed\\Temp\\{CD617D66-03E4-4568-B4A6-579F3664F663}\\InstallFlashPlayer.exe"
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Macromed\\Temp\\{CD617D66-03E4-4568-B4A6-579F3664F663}\\InstallFlashPlayer.exe"
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),6,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:taskschd:TaskSettings_put_StartWhenAvailable 0x136520,-1: stub
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it successfully using Wine Staging 2.12, 32-bit and Windows 7 as configuration. First I installed Firefox and then in the same virtual drive I installed the latest Adobe Flash for Firefox